# Material-table: Is it possible to open detailsPanel by default?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm trying to create a subtable of the main React [Material-Table](https://material-table.com/).
Everything is working properly as it should work, details panel (subtable) is showing on toggle icon press.

Are there any ways to show it opened by default? I mean to remove the toggle icon and show the `detailPanel` right from the component render?

Here is how my mat-table looks like (I didn't want to insert the whole component code, cause it will be too much code, full code is in the sandbox):

```
<MaterialTable
        icons={tableIcons}
        tableRef={tableRef}
        columns={tableColumns}
        data={tableData}
        onRowClick={(evt, selectedRow) =>
          setSelectedRow(selectedRow.tableData.id)
        }
        title="Remote Data Example"
        detailPanel={detailSubtable}
        options={{
          rowStyle: rowData => ({
            backgroundColor:
              selectedRow === rowData.tableData.id ? "#EEE" : "#FFF"
          })
        }}
      />
```

And a link to the **[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-change-width-of-column-4sbvf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)**

Comment: According to comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57460159/how-to-control-programmatically-the-toggling-of-a-row there is no way. Maybe try to go with https://material-ui.com/components/tables/

Answer (score 0):

As per knowledge, there is not any proper way or props to achieve this but you can do native DoM manipulation.

Provide custom Icon in `DetailPanel` icon with some unique ID like this:

```
  DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <div id="my-id" style={{ display: "none" }}>
      <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />
    </div>
  )),
```

Now, On `componentDidMount` find this element and trigger a click event on it  and hide parent node like this

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const myToggler = document.getElementById("my-id");
    if (!!myToggler) {
      myToggler.click();
      myToggler.parentNode.style.display = "none";
    }
  }, []);
```

here is the [working sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-change-width-of-column-iqcgz?file=/src/index.js:2421-2610) forked from yours, let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the [source code](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/7f809a74100fc73e97e0f5f2262e123df6caf146/types/index.d.ts) There is a props called `defaultExpanded` which should  work but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/505) which is causing the issue of not opening the panel by default.

To make it work (until the issue is fixed), you can imperatively modify the material-table's component the state in the useEffect

**Like this**

```js
useEffect(() => {
    tableRef.current.state.data = tableRef.current.state.data.map(data => {
      console.log(data);
      data.tableData.showDetailPanel = tableRef.current.props.detailPanel;
      return data;
    });
  }, []);
```

[Working demo of your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-default-open-xxlh1?file=/src/index.js)

This **solution works** for any number of rows/detailsPanel.